# How do I figure out why one host is so slow writing to another host on LAN?

Tags: linux, networking, macos, ubuntu, macbook

I have 3 devices on my LAN, all using wired connections:

1. MacBook Air
2. Lenovo ThinkCentre (running Ubuntu Server 22.04)
3. Raspberry Pi

I am using the ThinkCentre as a home server, and want to write large media files to it from the MacBook. I found the transfer speed unaccountably slow, so I put [iPerf](https://iperf.fr/) on all 3 machines to test.

**Long story short:** Having the MacBook send to the ThinkCentre yields an average of **8 Mb/s**, while every other combination of tests (notably including MacBook to Raspberry Pi and Raspberry Pi to ThinkCentre) results in **300 Mb/s**!

So it appears there is some network-related bottleneck specifically in the MacBook connecting to the ThinkCentre... but I have no idea what that could be.

**What can I try next to get to the bottom of this?**

Comment: Open Admin Tools, Resource Monitor on the Lenovo System, start up a transfer and see if that sheds any light

Comment: @John Ah, the ThinkCentre is running Ubuntu, actually. I've updated the Q to clarify. Thanks!

Comment: Try Wireshark for Linux and see if that sheds light on throughput.  You may see gaps in the packet flow

Comment: which model raspberry pi? the pi3, while it has a gigabit NIC, its maximum actual throughput is about 300mbit - because it's actually a USB2 device

Comment: Mb/s (Megabits) or MB/s (MegaBytes)? how big are the files? does the mac have a physical network port, or is it connected via some other bus like USB/Lightning?

Comment: So all three have gigabit Ethernet ports all directly attached to the same gigabit Ethernet switch, and all three report the link speed as gigabit? What speed does IPerf measure from the ThinkCenter to the MacBook Air?